# Improving Master Detail SQL code performance

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

[image]

I need a report include names and sum of payment in `Payment1`, `Payment2` columns without duplicate.

So I write this:

```
(
  SELECT Pid1, SUM(Payment1) as sum1, COUNT(*) as number, _name
  FROM perform, Person
  WHERE perform.Pid1= Person.id
  GROUP BY _name, Pid1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT Pid2, SUM(Payment2) as sum2, COUNT(*) as number, _name 
  FROM perform, Person
  WHERE perform.Pid2= Person.id
  GROUP BY _name, Pid2
)
```

And output:
[image: Result:]
This code work but it's too slow. How can I have better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the number of times you join to `person` by moving the `union` to a subquery:

```
select  pers.id
,       perf_sum.sum_payment
,       perf_sum.count_payment
,       pers._name
from    (
        select  pid
        ,       count(*) as count_payment
        ,       sum(payment) as sum_payment
        from    (
                select  PID1 as pid
                ,       Payment1 as payment
                from    perform
                union all
                select  PID2
                ,       Payment2
                from    perform
                ) perf
        group by
                pid
        ) perf_sum
join    person pers
on      perf.pid = pers.id
```